# Case insensitive search in hibernate without criteria

Tags: hibernate, case-insensitive

I want to do case insensitive search in hibernate Query. I can do it with Criteria but it is not an option for me right now. The method which fire query takes a query string as input and it is used by other components. Is it possible to enable case insensitive for Hibernate session or prepare criteria object from hql query.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `lower` or `upper` functions mentioned [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-expressions).

```
from User u where lower(u.name) = 'scott'
```

Comment: I was searching for the same thing and came across the official docs according to the like you gave in your answer. Thank you.